# Target embedded YouTube video with time changing links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, youtube

I'm working on a web article with a You Tube embedded video. I want to provide links in the article that change what's playing in the video. For example if I have a 5 minute video that discussed several topics the links would allow the reader the fast forward to the relevant part in the video. I tried doing this by targeting the iframe with links to specific time codes, but they don't have any effect. Can this even be done in simple HTML? If so what am I doing wrong? If I need to use another technique what would be the simplest approach?

```
<!doctype=html>
    <html>
<head>
    <title>
        YouTube Test
    </title>
</head>
<!-- This document demonstrates how an embedded YouTube video can be targeted by time specified     links.
 This feature will allow articles to direct viewers to the specific step they need help with -->
<body>
YouTube Time Targeting Test
<iframe name="iframe_a" width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/b8bLtg9J1Oc"     frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <!-- Target to 00:18 -->
<p><a href="http://youtu.be/b8bLtg9J1Oc?t=30s" target="iframe_a" >Time 1</a></p>
    <!-- Target to 00:23 -->
<p><a href="www.youtube.com/embed/b8bLtg9J1Oc?t=23s" target="iframe_a" >Time 2</a></p>
    <!-- Target to 00:43 -->
<p><a href="www.youtube.com/embed/b8bLtg9J1Oc?t=43s" target="iframe_a" >Time 3</a></p>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try the [YouTube JS API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) instead, specifically the `player.seekTo` method

Comment: You could use ?start=x&end=y where x and y are the start and end times in seconds. Example: http://youtu.be/b8bLtg9J1Oc?start=30

Comment: that works for starting, but not stopping AFAIK

Comment: The big issue is the platform these knowledge base articles will be written on does not allow editors to use Javascript. Only HTML and some basic CSS. I can implement Javascript myself from the admin when writing articles, but I'd want to make it so KB authors could use this functionality as well. System is Oracle Knowledge Base.